# Write VLFeat GMM on file

Tags: c++, file, image-processing, vlfeat

I want to train a `VlGMM` in C++ from [VLFeat](http://www.vlfeat.org/) object on an image dataset and re-use it in different executions.

I would like to read and write it on file, but I didn't find any function for that. Is that possible?